# Football (soccer) match processing

Tags: algorithm, real-time

I want to implement football match processing and so I spent a lot of time to find good algorithms to do it. I have some data as input - players that have some parameters. Some of parameters are static while the match is processing (skills) and some of them are dynamic (physical state, psycological state) that are changing in process. Also I have external parameters that I can change manually. I don't need it to be so close to the real football (excluding result. 20:0 will be awful anyway). And the last main idea is that the same input will not lead to the same output. Some of middle calculations should return random values.

The algorithm should not be very slow because in the near future it will be necessary to process about 1000 matches at the same time step-by-step. Each step will be calculated once per 3 seconds. And also these steps should be logically linked because I will make graphic match process with all ball and players movements.

What algorithms can you recommend for me? I thought about neural network but I'm not sure that this is a good solution.

You will really help me because I spent about of a half of year to find it so thank you very much!

Comment: Do you want to make something where you have two sets of characters and than game just returns the result, or you want something more close to fifa cpu vs cpu?

Comment: @ArkadiuszRaszeja, it will be a little bit close to fifa, more to football manager. Some parameters, result calculation step-by-step, not at one time. Each step once per 3 secs. Realism is not the issue, just basic acts (goals, passes, dribbling, falls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have an "action" every 5 minutes of the game, so 90/5 = 18 actions. To make it more realistic you can choose random number like:

```
numberOfActions = round(10,20);
```

This number can appear as a lenght of you for().
Than you have interactions between defense and offence parameters of two sets of your players. Lets say each point of offenceA-defenceB creates ten per cent chance to succeed:

```
if((TeamA.Offence-TeamB.Defence)*10 > round(0,100))
{
  TeamA.points++;
}
```

Of course the goalkeeper can decrease this probability, maybe even significantly.
And so on. Of course you can make it more complicated. Like you can compare your stats only for certain players, depending on who's having the ball. Your both offence and defense parameters can be decreased by time and raised by condition:

```
TeamA._realOffenceValue = 
    TeamA.Offence*
    (1-i/numberOfActions)*
    (TeamA.leftOffencePlayer.Condition);
```

Remember that in games like football manager or Europa Universalis it's everything about cheating the player. Balancing the game is a job for many hours and nobody will make it for you on the forum :)

Comment: Of course, I understand that balancing is the other issue and I don't ask to help me with it. I just wanted to know if the necessary to me algorithm exists. Now I have just random result generation. It is fast, result is close to real but I can't event show text progress like 'the player ran close to goals and kicked the ball too high'. I don't talk about 2D graphic process